# How to avoid notice in php when one of the conditions is not true

Tags: php, boolean-operations

I've notice that when one of the two conditions in a php if statement is not true. You get an undefined index notice for the statement that is not true. And the result in my case is a distorted web page. 
For example, this code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loginAdmin']) && ($_SESSION['loginAdmin'] != '')) {
    header ("Location: loginam.php");
} else {
    include('head2.php');
}



if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) && ($_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
    header ("Location: login.php");
} else {
    include('head3.php'); 
}
?>
```

If one of the if statements is not true. The one that is not true will give you a notice that it is undefined.
In my case it says that the session 'login' is not defined. If session 'LoginAdmin' is used. What can you recommend that I would do in order to avoid these undefined index notice.

**EDIT**
This is where I check if the entered information is correct, for those who are asking.  It always redirects to the login page even if the login information is correct:

```
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ausername']);
        $pword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['apassword']);
        $idnam= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aydi']);

        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE  ID= '$idnam' AND admin = '$uname' AND admin_password = '$pword'";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);



        if ($result) {
            if ($num_rows > 0) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['loginAdmin'] = "1";
                header ("Location: ampage.php");
            }
            else {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['loginAdmin'] = "";
                header ("Location: loginam.php");
            }   
        }
        else {
            $errorMessage = "Error logging on, please try again.";
        }
```

Comment: Why are you testing the value of the variable if it is not set? How will a not-set variable ever have a value?

Comment: You can use `if (empty($_SESSION['loginAdmin'])) { ...` instead, it will make code more clear and readable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition is wrong, it should be:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['loginAdmin']) || ($_SESSION['loginAdmin'] == '')) {
    header ("Location: loginam.php");
} else {
    include('head2.php');
}
```

And:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || ($_SESSION['login'] == '')) {
    header ("Location: login.php");
} else {
    include('head3.php'); 
}
```

replaced `&&` with `||` and `!=` with `==`

> You get an undefined index notice for
>   the statement that is not true.

That's not the case, you get notice messages when you have some variables undefined. You can avoid this be using suppression operator `@` but it is not a good idea to use that because it slows down performance.

Also you can hide notice messages by putting this on top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

But again while on development, you must be aware of all errors and notices so this is not a good idea again unless you are sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loginAdmin']) && $_SESSION['loginAdmin'] != '') {
    //variable exists and is not empty
    include('head2.php');
} else {
    //variable does not exist or is empty
    header ("Location: loginam.php");
}
```

Comment: In addition, I'd use `if (!empty($_SESSION['loginAdmin'])) { ...`, for better readability

Comment: Good point. I'll leave my answer as is, so that the OP can see where they went wrong. But yes, that's definitely more readable.

Comment: when I do this one, it redirects me to the login page even if I entered the correct username and password

Comment: Where is the username and password check there?

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are weird.
for example: `!isset($_SESSION['login']) && ($_SESSION['login'] != '')`
First, you check wether 'login' is NOT set in the session variable `!isset($_SESSION['login'])`
So if it is not set you will also check the second condition, in which you try to access the 'login' index, **which isn't set**.

Maybe you mean this condition?
`if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || ($_SESSION['login'] == ''))`
If login is not set, OR it is empty, redirect to login
otherwise redirect to head 3.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use || (OR)instead of && (AND).
2) change != to ==

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want `isset($_SESSION['login'])` instead (without "!")?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) && ($_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
```

It doesn't make much sense to test if `$_SESSION['login']` if you already know it's not set. If you remove the "!", it eliminates the notice because `isset` silences it and the second condition will never be evaluated when the index is not set.

Answer (score 0):

If the session is not set (`!isset($_SESSION['loginAdmin'])`) then the second condition in the if statements are really unnecessary, because they will never be true. You cannot have an undefined variable (the first condition) with a value (the second condition).

The error occurs because the variable you're testing in the second condition (after the `&&`) does not exist.

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loginAdmin'])) {
    header ("Location: loginam.php");
    exit;
} else {
    include('head2.php');
}



if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    header ("Location: login.php");
    exit;
} else {
    include('head3.php'); 
}
?>
```

I included `exit` after your header calls because otherwise the code will continue running, probably causing undefined behavior.

Comment: it seems that this code contradicts with the other. Causing my page to always redirect to login page even if the entered username and password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A quick example of operator evaluation:

```
function returnFalse() { echo "returning false\n"; return false; }
function returnTrue() { echo "returning true\n"; return true; }

echo "false && true\n";
if (returnFalse() && returnTrue()) {
    echo "True!\n";
} else {
    echo "False!\n";
}

echo "\ntrue && false\n";
if (returnTrue() && returnFalse()) {
    echo "True!\n";
} else {
    echo "False!\n";
}

echo "\ntrue && true\n";
if (returnTrue() && returnTrue()) {
    echo "True!\n";
} else {
    echo "False!\n";
}
```

This experiment demonstrates that the `&&` operator can only short-circuit if the first operand is false. Let's examine where the code fails.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) && ($_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
    header ("Location: login.php");
} else {
    include('head3.php'); 
}
```

The condition, in words, is this: if `$_SESSION['login']` does not exist, and `$_SESSION['login']` is not an empty string. We can never, ever want to access a key that does not exist in the `$_SESSION` array, and we know the `&&` operator will only short-circuit if its left operand is false.

The left operand is `$_SESSION['login']` does not exist. This is true if `$_SESSION['login']` does not exist, meaning the `&&` operator must look to the right operand to see if it is also true. Now `&&` looks at the condition `$_SESSION['login']` is not an empty string. Whoops! This condition accesses `$_SESSION['login']` which we have already, at this point, determined doesn't exist!

Answer (score 0):

if the sesion variable loginAdmin is not set then you don't want to evaluate the second condition where you check if it is an empty string. You can use [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to help you here. Change your code to

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['loginAdmin']) || ($_SESSION['loginAdmin'] == '')) {
    header ("Location: loginam.php");
} else {
    include('head2.php');
}



if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) || ($_SESSION['login'] == '')) {
    header ("Location: login.php");
} else {
    include('head3.php'); 
}
?>
```